# Firebase Deploy only hosting NO functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

In the project I'm currently working on, I have set up Firebase hosting and cloud functions.

I thought that I could only deploy functions like this: `firebase deploy --only hosting --token %FIREBASE_TOKEN%` However, when I run the command it also deploys the cloud functions. Am I doing something wrong? How can I deploy ONLY the changes I've made in hosting without re-deploying the cloud functions.

Thank you!

Comment: If the CLI doesn't work the way you expect, you should file an issue on GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/

Comment: Please include your `firebase.json` file

Comment: Look in your `package.json` file under `scripts` for a potential culprit.

Comment: @RafaelZasas here you can see the contents of firebase.json

https://gist.github.com/ezequieltejada/a5db9dc459499328c7e720c434fd3aae

Comment: @fakegirlfriends What do you mean? Does `firebase deploy --only hosting` runs any specific "npm run .... " in the background?

Comment: Maybe you need to come up with your own script since these projects share a folder. Have you considered using separate folders?

Comment: Yeah, I've considered it, but I want to leave it as a last resort.